# Is my design of encrypting message secure?

Tags: api, security, encryption, rsa

I am currently working on a web API. I need to ensure that the message sent from client to server is security enough (cannot be modified, read by attacker and able to identify the clients).

I have a preliminary design here. Is it secure enough?

I decided to make use of PKI. That is,
Both server and clients have a set of RSA public and private keys.
The server also have a database to store the client IDs and their public keys.

Before client and server communicate, they establish the session key using diffie-hellman key exchange. The "secret" used in diffle-hellman is the private key. The messages sent will be encrypted by the sender's private key. So, the receiver can identify the sender by using sender's public key, and man-in-the-middle attack is prevented. Then a session key K is established.

Then the client send a message to server:
Client send: Client ID, E(K, message), H(K, E(message), ClientID)
where H() is the hash function of SHA256.

When the server receives the message, it calculate H(K, E(message), ClientID) and compare it with the HMAC received. If they are equal, then the message should be secured.

I know that my design cannot prevent replay attack. But I am not considering it at this stage. Is my design secure enough? Any comment will be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel here?  Are standard mechanisms like SSL/TLS not sufficient here?

Comment: I just try to work and learn the stuff inside.

Comment: It's better to ask such questions on http://crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more appropriate for crypto.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you wrote, the first thing I thought about is a replay attack. You can prevent it by adding timestamp or counters to the messages (such that every two messages are different).

Additionally, notice that you still have to worry about the how to distribute the public keys.
If you do it over the Internet, so without Certificate Authority (CA) - you might be exposed to MitM attack when you try to get the public key!

The problem of getting some authentic key is crucial, and in my opinion - this is the main problem that SSL comes to deal with (it does so using CAs). Encryption and authentication given authentic symmetric key is easy! (using encryption and MAC)

Additional thing: 
What is H? hash function or HMAC? both are different things!

You wrote: H(K, E(message), ClientID). If you refer H as MAC (MAC has a key) and K is the key, it is better to use different keys for the MAC and the encryption. If not - I don't think you should send hash/MAC on your key.

And two last things:

1. Someone can just contact the server many times (each time as new client) and causes DoS attack.
2. Why do you save the public key of the client? In the first (hopefully secure) connection, where the server first knows the client, you can create the symmetric key and save it! It shorter and much more efficient.